# <kbd>, Superscript and Subscript, markup shortcuts

Tags: script, editing, tampermonkey, markdown, keyboard-shortcuts

#### About:

This script adds buttons and keyboard shortcuts that make it easy to add/remove:

- `<kbd>` tags
- Superscripts and subscripts
- `<del>` tags
- `<br>` tags
- `&emsp;`

when editing posts.

#### Old Screenshot <sup><sub>(Last 3 tags not shown)</sub></sup>:

[image: This script in action]

#### To use:

Click the button or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> on the keyboard and `<kbd></kbd>` will be inserted at the cursor.
If text is selected, it will be wrapped by the `<kbd>` tags instead.

Likewise for the Superscript and Subscript tags, the keyboard shortcuts are <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> (Up arrow and Down arrow).

The delete (semantic strikethrough) shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.
While breaks (`<br>`) are inserted via click or the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> shortcut.
And `&emsp;`s use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

**Tags are wrapped and unwrapped the same way that other markup** (Bold, Italic, etc.) is -- including how whitespace and nested tags are handled.

**Update:** `<kbd>` now **wraps in word mode.**  So `Ctrl P` becomes `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>`, etc.
All other tags wrap normally <sup><sub>(unless they don't have an end tag)</sub></sup>.

#### Download / Install:

[Install the script from GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js): [**<kbd>Install</kbd>**](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js)

Requires *Tampermonkey*, *Violentmonkey*, or equivalent userscript engine.

#### Code:

Find the source on GitHub at: [**BrockA/SE-misc/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js**](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Add_kbd_sup_sub_shortcuts.user.js)

You may also make bug reports, pull-requests, etc. there.

---

Inspired by the question, ["Markdown syntax for `<kbd>foo</kbd>`"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/130074/148310).

Comment: Nice work, Brock!

Comment: I was shown an error message saying to check my browser's console, and when I did there was this message: "This version of the "StackExchange, Add kbd shortcut" script is broken and obsolete.

Please uninstall it and (optionally) install the fixed and upgraded script." But what I can't figure out is how to *uninstall* my current version. There is nothing about it in the README file, nor is it listed with my other Firefox add-ons. I installed it long ago and don't even remember how I installed it to begin with. Can you please document the steps for uninstalling? (P.S. great add-on!)

Comment: @Mentalist Okay, I put a task to add such instructions in my todo list.  Meanwhile, for Firefox from the Add-ons manager (Ctrl Shift A), you should see a "Userscripts" entry in the left-hand column. Click it and then you can search for `kbd` and use the remove button.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thank you for the tip! I was looking in Extensions and that's why I didn't see it. All set now. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Wrt the `<kbd></kbd>` insertion, how about this simple scenario: user has `Shift+Alt+P` and wants to convert it to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

**Current scenario:** user highlights all three keys individually and highlights them one by one. Boring! :(

**Proposed scenario:** user highlights the entire string (`Shift+Alt+P`) at once, presses Alt-K, and voila! It converts to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> :D

**Implementation problems:** I don't think there should be any. We only need to split the text selection by `-` or `+` characters, apply formatting individually to each one of them, and give the result back.

**GIF of this feature:** (thanks to WELZ)

[image: feature in action]

Comment: Added with version 4.0.

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

Why not use this to add the button? It preserves the integrity of other buttons, and ensures that a button does not get added twice (for example, when in the review section, it will only add the buttons to the editors which don't have it.

```
//params: text: text of button
//params: callback: a function which takes id of textarea as argument(useful in review section etc when there are multiple textareas) and does the magic encoded in the button
//identify: a unique identifier (for each type of button), that ensures that buttons are not added twice
//pic: optional background pic
function addbutton(text,callback,identify,pic){
    //Callback must take id of textarea as argument.
    $.each($('.wmd-container').not(".canhasbutton"+identify),function(){
    try{
        tid=$(this).find("[id^=wmd-input]")[0].id;
        row=$(this).find("[id^=wmd-button-row]")[0];
        lastel=$(row).find(".wmd-button").not(".wmd-help-button").filter(":last");
        if(lastel.length>0){
            px=parseInt(lastel[0].style.left.replace("px",""))+25;
            //add code for background-position of span as well later
            btn='<li class="wmd-button" style="left: '+px+'px; " onclick="'+callback+'(\''+tid+'\')"><span style="background-image:url('+pic+');">'+text+'</span></li>'; //TODO: do via jQuery
            $(btn).insertAfter(lastel);
        }
        this.className+=" canhasbutton"+identify;
    }catch(e){}
    })
}
```

Then you add a live listener for this (you already have, it seems).

It just makes it extensible :)

Comment: @Brock no problem. Or, if I get time today, I'll forkfix this ;-). Even better, I'll put it in the real git so that you can fork it/see diffs.

Comment: @Brock I have a working version used in http://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons. This can be easily extended--add your kbd handler to the `//methods` section. (via `window.kbd=InsertKbdTag`, where `InsertKbdTag` is the function copied from your script), and add an entry to `buttonconfig`

Comment: @Brock note that it interferes with your kbd buttons, so you may want to disable it(my script). Otherwise the buttons will be useless (keyboard shortcuts won't be, though)

Comment: Finally rolled this into the script with version 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can you please add in <del>strike-through</del> `<del>text</del>` and Line break `<br />`

Comment: Done with version 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Can you please add in `[tag:something]` (to work like the other features)

The icon can just be [tag](/questions/tagged/tag)

Comment: Running out of room for icons, and this is yet another kind of beastie, so may have to wait for version 5 (with customizable dialog). But I have wanted this for myself more than once...

Comment: For now you can add in a dropdown menu titled `more` for the other new ones until 5 is ready.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I've added a fix to point 3 over [here](https://gist.github.com/2476992) (it's forked)

It deals with `<kbd>[selected text]</kbd>` and `[<kbd>text</kbd>]`, where the `[]` denotes selection.

It will not deal with wierd stuff like `<kb[d>text</kbd>]`. (Could be done using regexes)

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [tampermonkey](/questions/tagged/tampermonkey) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I have a slow internet, so the webpage loading circle may still keep spinning while the `#wmd-input` textbox has already loaded. In this case, I've noticed that if I place my cursor into the textbox *before* the page loads, there are two instances of the five set of buttons that get inserted into my toolbar. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Below is the markup as seen in Chrome DevTools, notice how all `.tmAdded` buttons have been duplicated. Also, notice those `li#wmd-spacerX` that have been inserted into the markup (and that are causing those grey vertical lines in the photo above)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The entire extension doesn't function properly in the profile editor (`/users/edit/{UserID}`).

I can click on all of the buttons but nothing happens. **([GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTs8h.gif))**

---

This is probably related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322371/358161).

Comment: Well, *thats* annoying.  Can't you be like me and never edit your profile?  Seriously, I might wait until the 21st, to see if your MSE post gets results, and then address this if still needed.

Comment: @BrockAdams that's what I was thinking... wait to see if whatever fix they do/don't put forth will solve this.

Comment: @BrockAdams LOOK AT MY PROFILE! I EDIT IT DAILY! xD

Comment: But the `em-space`...

Comment: Forgot how easy the workaround could be.  Should be fixed with version 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the new Dark theme on StackOverflow site, all the custom buttons now have `B` button background:

[image: B in Dark mode]